# Regex is not matching for string c#

Tags: c#, regex

```
string val = "VFC - [C:\study\Run20315.5000]"
string pattern = "VFC - *C:\\study\\Rund.*"
```

I have written below expression but its getting false.

```
bool Match= Regex.IsMatch(val, pattern)
```

Comment: Hi, what is your expected output? What you want to extract from the `val` string?

Comment: If you provide exact requirements you will get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about the square brackets, the backslash before `d` is missing if you planned to match a digit and the backslashes must be doubled - or better - use a verbatim string literal. Also, note that `*` is a *quantifier* that makes the pattern preceding it match 0 or more times. If you need to match arbitrary text between two patterns, use `.*` or `.*?` and in case there can be line breaks, compile the pattern with `RegexOptions.Singleline`:

```
string pattern = @"VFC - .*C:\\study\\Run\d";
bool Match= Regex.IsMatch(val, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=VFC+-+.*C%3a%5c%5cstudy%5c%5cRun%5cd&i=VFC+-+%5bC%3a%5cstudy%5cRun20315.5000%5d) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=VFC%20-%20.*C%3A%5C%5Cstudy%5C%5CRun%5Cd):

[image]

**Details**

- `VFC -`  - literal `VFC -`  substring
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `C:\\study\\Run` - a `C:\study\Run` substring
- `\d` - a digit.

Comment: I upvoted, but i think the intent may have been optional brackets... maybe

Comment: @MichaelRandall If OP clarifies that I will edit the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I tried your pattern, it is OK. And I tried to remove last `]`, because `*` can contain it, then it works too ? As the same logic, I tried to remove first `[` because of  there is a `*` around that place too, but it fails. I have no idea why ? Thanks  a lot.

Comment: @EricTsui Because `*` is not `.*`, in that pattern you're matching the whitespace followed by `*`; instead at the end of the pattern you're matching any character (`.`) followed by `*` (which means match between 0 and unlimited times). They have different characters matching. `*` doesn't contain `]`, instead `.` contains `]` and any other characters.

Comment: @EricTsui Just let me know what you want. If your string contains `[` between `1` and `a`, then you must also match `[` in the pattern between `1` and `a`. Regex does not jump from one location to another in the string, it parses it from left to right, char by char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just tried to learn from the post and your answer, and found  pattern =  @"VFC - .*C:\\study\\Run\d.*" can work as well. But @"VFC - *C:\\study\\Run\d.*" can not work , because I missed a `.` before first `*`.

Comment: @EricTsui Then you need no `.*` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Upvoted for the answer and nice picture, may I know how to produce that picture :)

Comment: @ALFA Really appreciated for detailed explanation, I tried `.*` then it works finally. Good on you.